# Lodash differenceBy alternative

Tags: lodash

I am trying to find a way to differentiate between 2 object literals by a property from each.
I can get this working by using 2 `._forEach()`

```
_.forEach(forms, form => {
    _.forEach(this.sections, section => {
        if(form.section === section.name){
          section.inProgress = true;
        }
    });
});
```

However this does not seem ideal. I have tried with the `_.differenceBy`

```
_.differenceBy(forms, this.sections, 'x');
```

But I cant differentiate by the property name as the "name" that i want to check by is `name` in one of the arrays and `section` in the other.

I want to use something like

```
_.differenceBy(forms, this.sections, 'section' === 'name');
```

It there something in [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) for this?

Comment: Can you please give one complete input and output format? It is quite confusing

Comment: @RaR whats confusing .. i just want to filter 2 object literals by a property (name) that is different in one object to the other object's property (section)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`_.differenceWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#differenceWith) with a comparator that refers to a specified object property in each array:

```js
var forms = [{ 'name': 'somethingA' }, { 'name': 'somethingB' }];
var sections = [{ section: 'somethingB' }];

var result = _.differenceWith(forms, sections, function(arrValue, othValue) {
  return arrValue.name === othValue.section;
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```